# Image layout android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

There is my layout in android xml, but the image does not in the top of the layout. What can be the problem?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/description_imageview"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:src="@drawable/hand"
                       android:contentDescription="@string/app_version"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/first_help_textview"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="sdsjkfhsdjkfhsdkjfh skdfjh skjdfh skdjfh skjdfh skjdfh skjdhfk jshdfkjh  jskdfh skjdfh skdjfh skdjfh skdjfh skjdfh skjdfh skjdfh kjsdhf kjsdhfk jhs"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

add scale_type:
[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: Image should be at the top but there is some empty space.

Comment: tried android:adjustViewBounds attr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Setting `scaleType` to your ImageView

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Edit : Try Changing LinearLayout height :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't helped. It's scaled image and there is bad proportion..

Answer (score 1):

might be your image having white spaces or you can say some area covered by image is null

either crop your image first and eliminate all white space

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/description_imageview"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/hand"
                   ***android:scaleType="fitXY"***
                   android:contentDescription="@string/app_version"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't helped. It's scaled image and there is bad proportion...

Comment: so the only option is , eliminate white spaces in your image, try to open the image in paint or any other tool to edit and remove white spaces

Comment: In the image there is no white spaces. I have already edited an image.

Comment: it shows there is, as you showed the result after scale type.post your image

Comment: I post the image now, wait a sec

Comment: is the image is in png format , when you using it in android ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/description_imageview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/hand"
      android:contentDescription="@string/app_version"
      android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
/>
```

Comment: you can add layout_margin_Top property